# jq- in editable table style change function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table which is editable then i also have two button.
when i add some text in table and select it(using onclick the table coloumn ) after select the table and on click the left button the content in the td is move left (20px-first click 40-second click....) i want to change the font-weight in each click .i write some code here for change font-weight but its not working

```js
  $(function () {
                $("td.cat").dblclick(function () {
                    var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
                    $(this).addClass("cellEditing1")
                    $(this).html("<input id='value' type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
                })
            })
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("tr").on("click", function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected1');
                });
            });

            jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                $(".cat").on("click", function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
                });

                $("#key").click(function () {

                    var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
                    sl = sl >= 100 ? "100" : "+=20";

                    $(".selected").css({
                        "padding-left": sl

                    });
                    $(".cat.selected").each(function () {

                        var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("cellEditing2"));
                        var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
                        var isPaddingLeft20 = paddingLeft === 21;

                        var isPaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 41;

                        if (isPaddingLeft20) $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
                        else if (isPaddingLeft40) $(this).css("font-style", "italic");
                        else $(this).css("color", "grey");
                    });
                });
                $("#key1").click(function () {
                    $(".selected").css({
                        "padding-left": "-=" + "20"
                    });
                    $(".cat.selected").each(function () {
           
                        var paddingLeft = parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"));
                        var PaddingLeft20 = paddingLeft === 21;
                        var PaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 41;
                        if (PaddingLeft20) $(this).css("font-weight", "normal");
                        else if (isPaddingLeft40) $(this).css("font-style", "italic");
                        else $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
                    });
                });

            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
        div {
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        div {
        }

        .selected {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        .cat{
        
     border: 1px solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    width:90%;
   height:17px;
   font-size:15px;
   padding-left:-5px;
   color:rgb(178,178,178);
  
}
 .editableTable .cellEditing1 input[type=text]{ 
       width:100%;
     border:none;
      text-align: left;
     background-color:transparent;
     
      
  }.editableTable .cellEditing1 {
      padding: 0;
    height:1px;
 } 
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="key">left</button>
    <button id="key1">right</button>


    <table class="editableTable">
        <tr>
            <td class="cat">aaa</td>
            <td class="dog"></td>
            <td class="dog"></td>
        </tr>
        
        </table>
```

Comment: I've never seen syntax like this: `var PaddingLeft20 = paddingLeft === 21;` what does `var foo = bar === x;` mean? How does that work?

Comment: ya i think this calculation is not good can you please give me a simple calculation method

Comment: Sure just tell me what you expect the result should be in a range (ex. 50 to 70). and what variables are involved.

Comment: ya,my requirement is , when the padding left=20 the selcted div text shows in bold, for  padding left=40 it show as normal font style and when the padding left= < 60  the text color became gray color

Comment: if you do this using "add class" property ,that more comfort for me

Comment: Your code works.. There is one typo - in the second function $("#key1").click(function () { - There is a line - var PaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 41; Make that - var isPaddingLeft40 = paddingLeft === 41; Then font weight does change.

Comment: ya ,its working before editing,but its not working after editing

Comment: no sir you just see the ouput .after editing that table its not working